# How does the com.datastax.driver.core.utils.UUIDs.startOf works?

Tags: cassandra, uuid, datastax-java-driver

I've read the [documentation of com.datastax.driver.core.utils.UUIDs.startOf](https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/2.0/com/datastax/driver/core/utils/UUIDs.html#startOf-long-), but I still don't understand how two slightly different UUIDs give the same timestamp.
The UUIDs are:

- ceec16b0-fbd7-11e9-0000-016e21bbe39d
- ceec16b0-fbd7-11e9-0000-016e21bbe39c

Running these through `startOf` gives the output below. What I find strange is that both the timestamp and Unix timestamp are the same, even though the last character of the UUIDs differ between them.
[image]

Can anyone clarify how the UUIDs are converted to timestamps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UUID for same millisecond has a space to accommodate up to 10,000 different values (based on the [100-nanosecond intervals as per standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_1_(date-time_and_MAC_address))). Java driver, has a [code](https://github.com/datastax/java-driver/blob/3.x/driver-core/src/main/java/com/datastax/driver/core/utils/UUIDs.java#L314) that counts from 1 to 10,000 and don't allow to generate more values during that millisecond.

Comment: I get that for the same millisecond we can have 10000 distinct values, but I don't understand the relationship between those 10000 and the 100-nanosecond rule. Can you give me some more details, please?

Comment: Standard for time-based UUIDs says that the time part is 60 bits long and represent time with 100 nanoseconds increase (so in 1 millisecond we can get only 10,000 values), but it's very hard to achieve reliably, so driver just increases counters to generate the next one